# Multiple IF Condition in Code Igniter

Tags: codeigniter, if-statement, combobox

I want to show some data into table with two paramaters from combobox

When I choose combobox 'kategori' and combobox 'option', I want data can be show in table, but when I try this code :

```
 foreach ($filter as $f) {

            if ( ($f['name'] == 'kategori' && $f['value'] == 'cake') && ($f['name'] == 'option' && $f['value'] == 'sweet') ) {


                $totalRecord = $this->nas->countRecord($filter);
                $this->load->library('pagination');
                $config['base_url'] = base_url('transaksi/report_nas/show/');
                $config['total_rows'] = $totalRecord;
                $config['per_page'] = 10;
                $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
                $this->config->load('pagination');
                $this->pagination->initialize($config);
                $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
                $data['total'] = $config['total_rows'];
                $start = (($page - 1) * $config['per_page']);
                $data['no'] = $start + 1;
                $data['records'] = $this->nas->recordsList($start, $config['per_page'], $filter);
                $data['filter'] = $filter;
                $data['shop'] = $shop;
                (count($data['records']) > 0 ) ? $this->load->view('transaksi/report_nas/table', $data) : $this->load->view('noevent');

               }

            }
```

this syntax doesn't work :

```
if ( ($f['name'] == 'kategori' && $f['value'] == 'cake') && ($f['name'] == 'option' && $f['value'] == 'sweet') ) {
```

I have try this one too :

```
if ($f['name'] == 'kategori' && $f['value'] == 'cake') {
   if ($f['name'] == 'option' && $f['value'] == 'sweet')  {
```

both of them show no data.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting impossible condition. I would say that you are missing logical OR instead of AND. This line:

```
if ( ($f['name'] == 'kategori' && $f['value'] == 'cake') && ($f['name'] == 'option' && $f['value'] == 'sweet') ) {
```

should be chaned to:

```
if ( ($f['name'] == 'kategori' && $f['value'] == 'cake') || ($f['name'] == 'option' && $f['value'] == 'sweet') ) {
```

because *$f['name']* can not equal both *'kategori'* and *'option'* at the same time. It can be one or other, not both.

More about PHP logical operators can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).